# Include a user registration form within another form

Tags: 8, forms

I am trying to include a user registration form within a Commerce pane form.  I am currently using (within `buildPaneForm`):

```
$user_form = $this->entityFormBuilder->getForm(user_load_by_mail($this->currentUser->getEmail()), 'guest_checkout_profile');
$pane_form['user_form'] = $user_form;
$pane_form['user_form']['#tree'] = TRUE;
```

The user form simply isn't shown though.  I can add a test field that will show:

```
$pane_form['test'] = ['#type' => 'textfield', '#title' => 'test'];
```

`$user_form` has the correct form array, with the appropriate fields from the `guest_checkout_profile` form display mode.

I was pointed to [IPE's embedding a form within another form](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/panels/tree/panels_ipe/src/Form/PanelsIPEBlockPluginForm.php?h=8.x-4.x#n169), but I don't see how what I'm doing is different there (from a "get the form to show" standpoint - validation and submission I'll deal with if I get there :D).

Baby steps - how can I get the form to even be rendered?

Comment: You can't have a complete form within a form , neither HTML nor Drupal supports that. What you are referencing is *not* a full form, it's a configuration form for a plugin which is just a part of a form, kind of like a field widget. Have a look at inline entity form/paragraphs widgets for examples on how to use the entity form display to build the form elements and then process them again from a custom submit callback.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2774077